# Selenium code for Instagram stuck loading images and stops working

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, bots

Instagram liking bot code works perfect until an image couldn't load on Instagram. Then it stops working, I need an `if` statement to handle a scenario like this.

I don't know why but sometimes Instagram doesn't open images. It can be on the 4th one or the 50th one.

I just need some code where:
if Instagram couldn't find the like button, press next button. Here is what I have so far:

```
def likePhotos(self,amount):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.find_element_by_class_name('v1Nh3').click()
    i = 1
    while i <= amount:
        time.sleep(2)
        bot.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.find_element_by_class_name('coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow').click()
        time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try` and `except`.

```
def likePhotos(self,amount):
bot = self.bot
bot.find_element_by_class_name('v1Nh3').click()
i = 1
while i <= amount:
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        bot.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n').click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        # do somthing if error occurs
    bot.find_element_by_class_name('coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow').click()
    time.sleep(1)
i += 1
```

Comment: One thing I would add: I would invoke `WebDriverWait` before calling `bot.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n').click()`, and I would `except TimeoutException:`. It's generally worse practice to just use `except:` because you can swallow any other exceptions you might be seeing. Aside from that, this is the right way to handle this type of scenario.